Send Keyboard key press event to Unity's new input system
I have a Unity application which detects some action and sends Keyboard press event to another Unity application.
I use keybd_event to achieve this.
Sample code:
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private void MakeKeyboardEvent(byte key)
{
    keybd_event(key, 0, 1 | 0, 0); // 1|0 simulates key pressed
    keybd_event(key, 0, 1 | 2, 0); // 1|2 simulates key released
}
public void SimulateEnter()
{
    MakeKeyboardEvent(KeyCodes.KC_ENTER);
}
public class KeyCodes
{
    public const byte KC_ENTER = 0x0D;

    ...(Other key codes)
}


This works well when I use Unity's old input system.
Doesn't work with the new Input system.
Is there any way I can send an event like keybd_event which can be recognized by the new Input System?
Any help or suggestions on this would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

why do you go through key events and not directly expose some API you can talk to (e.g. using a local socket connection etc)?
